# Display an image at cursor position when hovering over a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement a function, that would open an image at where the cursor is, when hovering over an image. How can this be achieved? I have tried the code list below, but it doesn't seem to work. It makes my website unresponsive. Is there an way to make this work more properly?

```js
function interval() {
    while (true) {
        setInterval(showImage, 1);
    }
}

function showImage() {
    var x = clientX;
    var y = clientY;
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
    image.style.left = x;
    image.style.top = y;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="interval()">THIS IS THE LINK</a>

<div style="display: none;" id="image">
   <img src="picture.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your image visible.

Add the listener only once on pointermove to not blow up the browser.

```js
let attached = false;
 
let imageContainer = document.querySelector("#image");

const followMouse = (event) => {
  imageContainer.style.left = event.x + "px";
  imageContainer.style.top = event.y + "px";
}

function showImage() {
  if (!attached) {
    attached = true;
    imageContainer.style.display = "block";
    document.addEventListener("pointermove", followMouse);
  }
}

function hideImage() {
  attached = false;
  imageContainer.style.display = "";
  document.removeEventListener("pointermove", followMouse);
}
```

```css
#image {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onpointerenter="showImage()" onpointerleave="hideImage()">THIS IS THE LINK</a>

<div id="image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment and reply. It is very helpful. This works very well for the link element. Do you know if there is a way to achieve this for 2 different text links in the same file, where each has a different picture on hover? Fo example I have a list of three links, and I want each one to open a different picture on hover. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Of course it's possible. For example, you can modify the `src` of your `img` element by passing a parameter to your showImage() function `onpointerenter="showImage('myAwesomeUrl')"`.

Comment: Thanks again! Do you mean the showImage() function that is placed inside the <a> tag? Or in the JS file. I am kinda new to javascript and don't know a lot about the way JS is used properly... Would each image for different links have their own function like so: onpointerenter="showImage('myAwesomeUrl-picture 1')", onpointerenter="showImage('myAwesomeUrl-picture 2')" etc.?

Comment: 1) Inside javascript
2) yes

Comment: @Zharko I saw you opened a new question with the code I wrote for a different problem, that's a good thing. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

This would actually work better using css instead of javascript, see demo below:

```css
.interval:hover ~ #image {
  display: block;
}

.imageParent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="interval">THIS IS THE LINK</a>

    <div class="imageParent" id="image">
      <img width="200px"
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Node.js_logo.svg/1200px-Node.js_logo.svg.png"
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the information. However, in your suggestion the image does not follow the cursor position, as stated in the question. This is achievable using javascript.

Comment: @Zharko well, it's not stated in your question, anyway someone else utilized javascript in his/her answer down below

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
    #imageContainer {
      opacity: 0; # Not visible
    }
    
    #linkWithImage:hover ~ #imageContainer {
      opacity: 1; # Visible
    }
```

```html
    <a id="linkWithImage" href="https://www.breakingbadstore.com/">Link with image</a>
   
    <div id="imageContainer">
        <img src="https://gcdn.emol.cl/mitos-y-enigmas/files/2019/09/breaking-bad.jpg" width="500px"  />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove",function (e) {
            var body = document.querySelector('body');
            var bubbles = document.createElement("span");
            var x = e.offsetX;
            var y = e.offsetY;
            bubbles.style.left = x+'px';
            bubbles.style.top = y+'px';
            var size = Math.random() * 100;
            bubbles.style.width = 20 + size+'px';
            bubbles.style.height = 20 + size+'px';
            body.appendChild(bubbles);

            setTimeout(function () {
                bubbles.remove();
            },4000)
        })
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}


span{
    position: absolute;
    background: url(https://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100%{
        transform: translate(-50%, -1000%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```